# How to add default base styles for specific HTML elements in UnoCSS?

Tags: css, unocss

Coming from Tailwind where I could do something like this:

```
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply text-2xl;
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to find something equivalent in Uno. The only thing I found are Preflights, but they only support raw CSS and not rules/custom rules. How can I add default base styles for specific HTML elements?

Comment: I would love an answer to this question. I find UnoCSS severely lacks in documentation on how to actually use it in a project. I don't want to bring down the project as I love the concept of UnoCSS. It just looks like a amazing toolkit without any instructions on what you can build with it.